# Сортировка товаров по одному товару от каждого продавца MYSQL 8

Tags: mysql

Есть следующая структура таблицы. id, seller_code, seller_rating.

```
id (int) AI,
seller_code (int),
seller_rating (int)
```

Нужно сделать выборку отсортированную по рейтингу продавца по одному товару от каждого продавца.

Т.е. выбираются по одному товару от каждого продавца (seller_code) отсортированные по seller_rating, далее выбираются следующие по одному товару от каждого продавца (seller_code) отсортированные по seller_rating и т.д.

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `seller_code` int NOT NULL,
  `seller_rating` int NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;  

ALTER TABLE `items`  
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);  

INSERT INTO `items` (`id`, `seller_code`, `seller_rating`) VALUES
(1, 1, 3),
(2, 1, 3),
(3, 1, 3),
(4, 1, 3),
(5, 2, 2),
(6, 2, 2),
(7, 2, 2),
(8, 2, 2),
(9, 3, 1),
(10, 3, 1),
(11, 3, 1),
(12, 3, 1);
```

Результат

```
(1, 1, 3)  
(5, 2, 2)  
(9, 3, 1)  
(2, 1, 3)  
(6, 2, 2)  
(10, 3, 1) 
(3, 1, 3)  
(7, 2, 2)  
(11, 3, 1) 
(4, 1, 3)
(8, 2, 2)
(12, 3, 1)
```

MYSQL 8

Comment: Добавьте в текст вопроса: CREATE TABLE скрипт таблицы (описание - это ни о чём), пример данных (3-5-10 строк в формате INSERT INTO скрипта) и требуемый результат для этих данных. И ещё - укажите ТОЧНУЮ версию MySQL.

Comment: Дополнил данные.

Comment: По одному товару с самым высоким рейтингом в разрезе продавца? Или по какому одному товару продавца, случайному или каждому?

Comment: 1) Покажите ПОЛНЫЙ требуемый результат. 2) Объясните, почему именно так (почему запись `(1, 1, 3)` именно первая, почему `(5, 2, 2)` именно вторая и т.п.). PS. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=04facb19d8cc1b539191359d2dc06035) с данными.

Comment: Все товары отсортированые по рейтингу продавца по одному от каждого продавца, циклами.

Comment: Основная суть - высший рейтинг поставщика и от него один товар, далее следующий поставщик с низшим рейтингом и от него один товар и т.д.. Когда цикл прошел и от каждого поставщика выбралось по одному товару далее цикл повторяется снова. Можно добавить второстепенную сортировку по id. В результате видно: первые три товара от разных продавцов отсортированных по рейтингу продавцов, следующие три ДРУГИХ товара от этих же продавцов отсортированных по рейтингу продавцов и т.д.

Comment: (1, 1, 3) именно первая - потому что сортируем по seller_rating (3). почему (5, 2, 2) - потому что сортируем по seller_rating (2) на id можно внимания не обращать. приоритет seller_rating.